# Get width of div with no explicit css width using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, positioning

Supposing i have a rectangular div which is filled with a span and some amount of padding around it and thus no explicit height and width in css, Is it possible by using jquery to get the explicit width of the div before it is rendered?

The widths and height of the div would depend on how much word and in the span.

Comment: Have you tried using width()?

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem, could you tell us more about X?

Comment: height and width for a found element is always available via JS or jQuery, even if the values are Zero.  what is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

The [`.width`](https://api.jquery.com/width/) jQuery method is what I suppose you are looking for.

From the docs:

[image]

Returns exact value without including the padding, border and margin.

Answer (score 2):

It's impossible to get width of an element before it was rendered and placed into the DOM. You can get the total width after that, it includes padding and everything:

```
$("div").width();
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you mean by "before it is rendered", you may be able to use `.width()` or `.outerWidth()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't measure a div before its rendered, because its the browser's rendering engine that's actually responsible for determining the width of the div.

You can go around showing the div by giving it a css class with `opacity: 0` and then use jQuery's `.width()`:

```
$('SELECTOR').width()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `Element.clientWidth`. It has some limitations as listed [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.clientWidth)

```
var element = document.getElementbyId('id');
console.log(element.clientWidth);
```

Since this is the usable width in the div, I think this is what you are looking for.